# ImportError: cannot import name 'DeprecationDict'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, dask, gridsearchcv, dask-ml

I'm trying to import dask_searchcv and error is thrown while import other module `DeprecationDict`.

I have installed dask_searchcv Version: 0.2.0, and scikit-learn
Version: 0.21.3

I tried importing the dark_searchcv as shown below:

```py
import dask_searchcv as dcv
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b8082b897401> in <module>
      1 # Instantiate the grid search model
----> 2 import dask_searchcv as dcv
      3 # grid_search = dcv.GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, cv = 3)
      4 # grid_search.fit(data, target)
      5 # grid_search.best_params_

~/.virtualenvs/dask-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_searchcv/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from .model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
      4 
      5 from ._version import get_versions

~/.virtualenvs/dask-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask_searchcv/model_selection.py in <module>
     52 
     53 if _SK_VERSION >= '0.19.1':
---> 54     from sklearn.utils.deprecation import DeprecationDict
     55     _RETURN_TRAIN_SCORE_DEFAULT = 'warn'
     56 

ImportError: cannot import name 'DeprecationDict'
```

I have tried re-installing sklearn using `pip3 install -U scikit-learn` but issue still remains unresolved.

**Note: I'm running above code using jupyter notebook**

Answer (score 2):

`dask-searchcv` is deprecated, as noted in the docs: https://dask-searchcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You want `dask-ml` and you should update your import as `import dask_ml.model_selection as dcv`.